# Why is a button clickable when theres another layout overlaying it?

Tags: android, layout, onclick, android-linearlayout

I got a Layout which is relatively positioned.
In it I got (by now) two things:

- A Clickable Button which is bound to an onClick-Event
- A LinearLayout which is overlaying the full screen

Although the LinearLayout is overlaying the button, the button is still clickable.
Even if there's another button in the overlay.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright I found an approach that works together with animation:

The Layout (shortened):

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <Button ... />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/underlay" android:background="#00ffffff" />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/overlay" ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now when Fading In "overlay" it seems to be the best to have an invisible "underlay" which is immediately put to VISIBLE:

```
LinearLayout underlay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.underlay);
underlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
underlay.setOnClickListener(...);
//now animate the overlay
```

Answer (score 8):

The overlaying views (and layouts) have to implement an onClick listener to catch the event, otherwise the event is dispatched on the underlaying views.

Comment: This is what i tried but it didnt make a change:
           [`code`](sidebar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
  });)

Comment: mmm, onTouch listener will work then (if your onTouch implementation returns true).

Comment: Okay seems that this is NOT working when animating... have to do a workaround with an invisible one behind

Comment: This is a known problem for the previous android versions. I also had the problem. The workaround a found was to have an invisible view on the entire screen which get all the click events, visibility=gone, and when the animation is running I set visibility=visible. Then no click is available during an animation.
Hope it helped